# Neo4j JavaScript driver - Subscribing to changes

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I'm trying to subscribe to changes in the database using `neo4j-javascript-driver`. Currently the `driver.rxSession()` is returning a stream or rows, instead I want to get a stream of results as the database changes. Currently I'm using this query:

```js
rxSession.run('match (n) return n')
  .records()
  .pipe(
    toArray()
  )
```

I'm not sure how resource intensive it's gonna be on Neo4j to update on every change on the query result, but does the driver support such a behavior or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [plugin](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/4.0/extending-neo4j/) to monitor all changes to the DB, but it will have to be written in Java.

And you can take a look at how the APOC plugin's [trigger](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/background-operations/triggers/) procedures are [implemented](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/tree/4.0/src/main/java/apoc/trigger) for some ideas.